# SQLite subselect conundrum

Tags: sqlite

Data (illustrative) in SQLite3. Have a few million rows, actually.

```
a, aardvark
a, anvil
a, apple
a, automaton
b, apple
b, peanut
b, persimmon
b, walnut
```

Key for my data is actually multiple columns but here I've just used the first column.

So, I'd like to find all the keys that are associated with apple, then use that to query all the other values associated with those keys.

Something like

```
select * from data where key in (select key from data where element = apple);
```

But that isn't working, perhaps because of the multi-column keys:

```
 select *  
 from data 
 where k1, k2, k3, k4 in (select k1, k2, k3, k4 from data where element = "apple");
```

Thoughts?  Thanks!!

TC

Comment: I'm wondering if this is just an inner join on itself, but still unsure how to handle given multi-column keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all the data:

```
select *
from data d1
left join data d2 ON (d1.k1 = d2.k1) AND (d1.k2 = d2.k2) AND etc...
where d1.element = "apple"
```

Then you'll have to clean-up the results to exclude duplicates and do any other result-set preparation you may be interested in.

Comment: Ryan, this saved my bacon -- and frankly made me leave SQL forever.  I'm now moving to Redis....

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Ryan's idea, but the `DISTINCT` already eliminates duplicate keys, and the `NATURAL` join avoids the need to write out all the key comparisons:

```sql
SELECT d1.*
FROM data AS d1
NATURAL INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT k1, k2, k3, k4
                    FROM data
                    WHERE element = 'apple'
                   ) AS d2
```

(Natural joins can be dangerous because it is possible that the tables could be unintentionally changed later so that more columns have matching names, but here it's safe because `d2`'s columns are explicitly listed.)